# Load Trie into Memory

Tags: java, c#, memory-management, data-structures

I have a sizeable trie stored in a RDBMS. The trie size is 5GB and growing.
Because of strict latency requirement (200 - 300 ms) I need to keep that loaded into the server RAM always.
I have a server with 16GB RAM.
How do I ensure that this trie is always served from RAM and avoid expensive Disk I/O?
I am writing a web-service which will access the trie from RAM and return result to the caller.
Language options are C#/Java.
Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Note: I have also gone through this great series https://lwn.net/Articles/250967/ about memory/cache management but could not find to answer this question.

Comment: An option would be to query the trie once, i.e. upon startup of the server. It resides then in a datastructure in the memory.

Comment: If I do a query at the startup and load the trie in a static variable? Will it ensure that the result is stored in RAM? Also, this would require me to have a JVM size in excess of 5 GB right?

Comment: Yes, it will reside in the RAM, except if your machine runs out of memory, then swapping will happen. To be honest, I don't now the actual size of the datastructure in the memory, maybe there is some overhead for the structure itself, except from the data.